# Actionscript 3 - Help 'saving' a value to a parameter of an eventListener

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, parameters, timer

this is the first question I've asked on this site before, and I don't feel I'm great with English, so I apologize in advance for any formatting or language errors, and I am also relatively new to programming, so I also apologize if I miss something basic or seem like an idiot.

I've been working on a small personal project for fun for a good while now, and I've started it from scratch about 3 times in attempt to use different methods, but I always encounter this same problem.

My final goal with this project is to allow the user to be able to click on the stage, moving a symbol (1 of 30, whichever is next in an array from 0-29) to where the person has clicked, disappearing when a timer relative to that symbol(e.g. symbol0 to timer0, symbol 1 to timer1, etc.) has finished counting, and the user will be able to place multiple symbols and therefore start multiple timers.
When the program is loaded, an array of timers is created, and a for loop adds names for each individual timer to the array, like so:

```
var timerNamesGreen:Array = new Array();
function addTimerName(s:String)
{
return("timer"+s)
}
for(var i:int = 0;i<5;i++)
{
timerNamesGreen.push(addTimerName("Green")+i)
}
```

I then attempt to attach an act timer to each name, as well as an event listener:

```
var timersActiveGreen:Array = new Array();
for(i = 0;i<timerNamesGreen.length;i++)
{
timerNamesGreen[i] = new Timer(1000,5)
timerNamesGreen[i].addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(te:TimerEvent):void{timeHandler(te,i)})
}
```

I also have the array "timersActiveGreen," for the purpose of determining which timer to start next when the user begins clicking on the stage.(0 is inactive, 1 is active. Each index of the array is meant to be aligned to the index of the timer it is representing.(timer at index 0 is active, timersActiveGreen[0] == 1))

And this is where my main problem comes in. With the event listeners, I wish to have it fire off to the timeHandler function with a parameter to determine which timer has ticked in the timeHandler function. But as it stands, I do not know how to accomplish this, as if I simply use i as the parameter, when the timer ticks and the eventListener is triggered, at that instant when the listener is triggered, i is not saved to be the value it was when the listener was added, but is instead 5 from adding the timers into the array. Thus, when I start a timer, regardless of which one is started, the parameter for the function timeHandler is 5, and therefore does not accurately represent the timer started.

My timeHandler function goes as so:

```
function timeHandler(event:TimerEvent, i:int)
{
    if(timerNamesGreen[i].currentCount = 5)
    {
    timerNamesGreen[i].reset();
    timersActiveGreen[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

So in other words, I would like to have a method of identifying which timer eventListener is calling for the timeHandler function, but I cannot think of how to do so.

I am attempting to use a method like this in order to avoid having a lot of lines of almost the same code, like stating timer after timer(I am planning to have 2 other colours, and possibly more than 30 timers, so that's at least 90 lines for stating timers alone, and another 90 or more for event listeners.)

I apologize if there's more information than needed, or lack of. If any corrections come to mind, or clarification is needed, please do not hesitate to correct me.

Any information you can provide would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would greatly benefit from creating an object class.  You could write all the functionality you want each symbol/timer pair to have, and instantiate new copies whenever you clicked.  That said, for the sake of directness, I'll address the question in the context you're attempting to solve it in.

---

### [Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html)

Rather than using an anonymous function to pass both the [TimerEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) and your custom index, you can store the timer as the key for an object.  In this way, when `TimerEvent.target` is referenced from your listener, you can immediately find the object it's associated with.  Ultimately, while you can use your approach, modifying/creating your own events can be *dirty* for your code, and adds (potentially) frustrating results.

The code below creates a simple demo that creates a symbol wherever you click, and updates each circle's label with the `currentCount` of the timer.

```
function createCircle():MovieClip {
    // This creates a circle, with random color.
    var circle:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    circle.graphics.beginFill(Math.floor(Math.random() * (1+0xFFFFFF-0x000000)) + 0x000000);
    circle.graphics.drawCircle(22, 28, 15);
    circle.graphics.endFill();

    // We'll update this textfield ever time the timer ticks
    var txt:TextField = new TextField();
    txt.name = "txt";
    txt.selectable = false;
    circle.addChild(txt);

    return circle;
}

var currentIndex:int = 0; // Keeps track of which symbol to use
var symbolArr:Array = []; // Stores our circle and timer
var timerToSymbol:Dictionary = new Dictionary(); // Uses timer as the key for each circle

stage.addEventListener("mouseUp", stageClick)

// Create X number of circles in the array;
for (var i:int = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    symbolArr[i] = {
        "circle":createCircle(),
        "timer":new Timer(1000, 5)
    }

    timerToSymbol[symbolArr[i].timer] = symbolArr[i].circle;
    symbolArr[i].timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateSymbol);
}

function stageClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // Place the next circle at mouse coordinates
    addChild(symbolArr[currentIndex].circle);
    symbolArr[currentIndex].circle.x = e.stageX;
    symbolArr[currentIndex].circle.y = e.stageY;

    // Reset the timer (and text), and start the countdown.
    symbolArr[currentIndex].timer.reset();
    symbolArr[currentIndex].circle.getChildByName('txt').text = "0";
    symbolArr[currentIndex].timer.start();

    // Update our index within the confines of the array length.
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % symbolArr.length;
}

function updateSymbol(e:TimerEvent):void {
    // Every time we tick, update the text to the current count.
    var txt:TextField = timerToSymbol[e.target].getChildByName('txt');
    txt.text = e.target.currentCount;
}
```